# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un determinado paquete de npm está instalado?

Tags: npm

¿Cómo puedo saber si está instalado un determinado paquete de npm? Por ejemplo, antes de ejecutar:

```
npm install -g typescript@2.0.0
```

¿Cómo puedo saber si ese paquete ya está instalado en la PC?

Comment: ¿en qué sistema?

Comment: En el sistema OSX

Comment: Te podes fijar en el package.json si estas haciendo algun proyecto con javascript, en dependencies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lamentablemente no hay una instrucción como `npm check` para saber si está instalado actualmente. El comando que te puede servir es `ls` que te muestra una lista de los paquetes instalados. Este comando es *pipable*, es decir, que su salida puede integrarse en la entrada de otro comando.

**Bash**

```
npm ls | grep typescript
```

**Powershell**

```
npm ls | select-string typescript
```

**Dos**

```
npm ls | findstr "typescript"
```

Es cierto que lo anterior no es tan rápido; tomará más tiempo mientras más grande sea la lista de paquetes instalados. Sin embargo, puedes crear un script para que haga una búsqueda por nombre de paquete.

**Ejemplo**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const path = require('path');


const DEPS_DIR = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');

if (!process.argv[2]) { // los dos primeros argumentos son "node" y la ruta del script
  return console.log('\x1b[31m', 'Error: nombre de paquete inválido');
}

checkModule(process.argv[2].toLowerCase())
  .then(files => {
    console.log('\n[+] Packages found:\n');
    files.forEach(file => {

      let packageInfo = `${DEPS_DIR}/${file}/package.json`;
      let reader = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(packageInfo)
      });

      reader.on('line', line => {
        if (line.includes('version')) {
          let version = line.split(':')[1].replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
          console.log('\x1b[32m', `${file}@${version}`);
        }
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });


function checkModule(input) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(DEPS_DIR, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(
          new Error('No existe node_modules en este directorio')
        );
      } else {
        resolve(
          files
            .filter(file => file.toLowerCase().includes(input))
        );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Añade el código anterior en un fichero llamado `check-module.js` y agrégalo en `node_modules` global. El paso siguiente es hacer un script en bash y batch para ejecutar el script. Llama estos script `check-module` y `check-module.cmd` para Unix y Windows respectivamente.

**Unix**

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/check-module.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/check-module.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

**Windows**

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\check-module.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\check-module.js" %*
)
```

Por último, solo ejecuta en cualquier proyecto:

```
check-module <nombre>
```

Y tendrás una lista de paquetes con su respectiva versión en muy poco tiempo.

---

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, como comentaba a Ivan Botero, tarda 12 segundos la ejecución del "npm ls", parece ok la salida ¿Pero habrá alguna forma más directa?

Comment: El proceso tardará más mientras más grande sea la cantidad de paquetes instalados. Lamentablemente no existe un comando para ello.

Comment: @PabloEzequiel He actualizado mi pregunta. He escrito un pequeño script para verificar si un paquete está instalado mostrándote también la versión si lo encuentra.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, gracias por el esfuerzo de compartir el script. Seguí los pasos, pero algo no me funcionó... igualmente para el tema de la pregunta, al menos en mi caso particular, voy a utilizar la variante del "npm ls | grep typescript" que comentabas al inicio de la pregunta, aunque tarde un poco. Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda y saludos

Answer (score 7):

Puedes usar

```
npm list -g | grep PAQUETE
```

> -g: Segun la documentacion
>
> The -g or --global argument will cause npm to install the package globally rather than locally. See npm-folders.

En pocas palabras este busca de una manera global entre todos los paquetes de `npm`

En mi caso, cuando ejecuto este comando:

```
npm list -g | grep "type"
```

Obtengo

```
  | | `-- typedarray@0.0.6
  | +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0
  | +-- mime-types@2.1.12
```

**Recuerda:**

`grep` tiene varios parametros utiles:

Si quieres que sea `case-insensitive` (no se fije en mayusculas), puedes usar `grep -i`.

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, me tarda 12 segundos hacer el "npm list" si bien muestra varios paquetes de tipo "typescript" que estoy buscando, me parece un poco lento ¿Existirá una forma más directa?

Comment: Es muy posible que no exista una manera de hacerlo mas rapido, puesto que ello depende de la cantidad de paquetes que esten instalados....Lo que si podrias hacer es guardar toda la salida en un archivo y posteriormente realizar el `grep` en ese fichero, mientras no cambie la lista de paquetes, podrias usarlo para filtrar varios

Comment: @PabloEzequiel Puedes probar Yarn como alternativa a NPM que es bastante más rápido: https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres Saber si un modulo de NPM esta instalado. 
puedes usar

`npm view <package-name> version`

y también te sirve para consultar su versión aveces es muy útil.
Cuando la librería no esta instalada te aparecerá así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Con los comandos de verificación del paquete en sí. Ejemplo:

- para saber de typescript: `tsc -v`
- para saber de angular: `ng version`